# Strage behaviour with SAX parser

Tags: xml, sax, saxparser

I am consuming some third party REST web service. What I am doing is parsing the response from it with SAX parser. In response I have a collection of `<section>` tags each of which contains a single `<text>` tag and some more. This text is basically a review of a product so user can type there anything he likes(or what is allowed on a web site of ws-provider).
I encountered a problem parsing this `<text>` tag in one place. Having a response with like 30 reviews only in one case it behaves oddly.

Here is a piece of xml being parsed

```
<text>Prachtige vormgeving. RVS/Zwart, zoals afbeelding hierbij. Even de handleiding doorlezen en daarna zeer handig in gebruik. Koffie is heerlijk. Heet water voor thee of zelfs kopje Nescafé. Cups zijn eur 0,31/0,33 per stuk. Via de site kan je een startersaanbieding met presentatiekist bestellen.&lt;br/&gt;Sommige onderdelen zijn natuurlijk heet, pas op met kinderhandjes. Kortom: zeer tevreden!!&lt;br/&gt; </text>
```

I have implemented `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler` where I did all the stuff. The weirdness is why my  `public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)` method is called twice for above piece of xml. I debugged and figured out that first time it is called with the `char[] ch` containing a text `"Prachtige vormgeving...."` and second time with an empty string, causing the real text to be overridden, thus I do not have a review text for these particular review item. Why is that? Is this a bug?

I made an additional check, if I already have the text then just ignore a text assignment for the next time. So it still works correctly.
Also I have figured out that when it is called second time the qName is an empty string while for the first time it is 'TEXT'. (It is in the `public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)` method). My java is 1.5_06, Deploying my app on OC4J 10.1.3.5.

So again, the question is: Is this a bug? Or a normal behavior and I just miss some knowledge about SAX parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should accumulate characters received in `characters`. The behavior you describe fits into the [SAX specification](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29). It is up to parser to decide when and how to call the `characters` method:

> The Parser will call this method to report each chunk of character
>   data. SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single
>   chunk, or they may split it into several chunks; however, all of the
>   characters in any single event must come from the same external entity
>   so that the Locator provides useful information.

Something like this could help (**not checked**):

```
class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    StringBuilder chars = new StringBuilder();
    ...
    private void flushCharacters() {
        char [] data = chars.toString().toCharArray();
        // use data as you want or use just chars.toString()

        chars.delete(0, chars.length());
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char [] data, int offset, int length) {
        chars.append(char, offset, length);
    }
    ...
    // call flushCharacters in 
    // startElement/endElement/processingInstruction and wherever you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying of some SAX concepts to me. Indeed I am new to it. I applied the accumulative approach you have suggested to the <text> tag and it's working. But the fact that the split is done only in this particular case, even though there are much larger <text>'s in response with much tricky content, is a mystery to me. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Also I have a small question left: Should I apply this accumulation to all tags? There are <date>, <name>, <label> but they have considerably much smaller content within. May they also be split? When running my app I do not see any.

Comment: @user1278890, yes you should. You cannot predict when the parser is going to chunk `characters` so your code must not rely on atomic `characters` events.